# Handling events in WinForm UI that have been raised in instance of a SignalR persistent connections endpoint class

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling, signalr

So, I have put together a simple class to create a SignalR server and starts the Owin.HttpListener and allow clients to connect which has worked fine so far:  Create server object , server object starts listener, client connects to listener, blah, blah, it works.

However, the issue I am having, is in trying to raise an event from the **EndPoint** class and handle it at the UI (**Form1**).  So far I have had ZERO luck in getting these events to work.

My assumption is it possibly has something to do with the UI running on the *Main thread* and the events raised in the **EndPoint** class are running on the *worker threads*? But, I have no idea if there is something else I am missing or what to do at this point.

The code below is what I have set up on my end. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Windows Form Calling Code:

```
 Public Class Form1
        Const ServerURI As String = "http://localhost:8081"

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            '' create object and start server
            Dim MyServer As New Server(ServerURI)

            AddHandler MyServer.OnClientConnected, AddressOf ConnectionHandled
        End Sub


        Public Sub ConnectionHandled(connectionID As String)
            MsgBox("It worked!")
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Code Referenced from Windows Form1

```
Public Class Server

    Private SignalR As IDisposable
    Private Property uri As String
    Private endPoint As EndPoint
    Public Event OnClientConnected(connectionID As String)

    Public Sub New(HostURI As String)
        _uri = HostURI
        StartServer()
        endPoint = New EndPoint
        AddHandler endPoint.OnClientConnected, AddressOf ClientConnected
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartServer()
        Try
            SignalR = WebApp.Start(uri)
        Catch ex As Exception
            '' Blah
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClientConnected(connectionID As String)
        '' raise event for calling code
        RaiseEvent OnClientConnected(connectionID)
    End Sub

End Class

Public NotInheritable Class EndPoint
    Inherits PersistentConnection

    Public Event OnClientConnected(connectionID As String)

    Protected Overrides Function OnConnected(request As IRequest, connectionId As String) As Task
        RaiseEvent OnClientConnected(connectionID)
        Return Me.Connection.Broadcast(String.Format("New Connectionn: {0}", connectionId))
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Startup

    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll).MapSignalR(Of MyEndPoint)("/signalr").MapSignalR()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks structurally wrong, from it I can't understand where all the pieces belong.

The `Server` class <strike>is trying to connect to the server, therefore belongs to the client, but then</strike> in its constructor it instantiates `Endpoint`, which in turn inherits from `PersistentConnection` and therefore has to live on the server, as for the `Startup` class, but you say that code is *referenced* from `Form1` and therefore it seems it runs on the client, which would be wrong.

Even if you just listed the server portions in the wrong place, it is simply wrong to try to instantiate <strike>`Endpoint`</strike> `Server` on the client. Other things look wrong too, like having the server-side `OnConnected` event directly raise a client side event.

So, I think you might miss some fundamentals about where pieces live with SignalR. IMO [you should go back to basics](http://www.asp.net/signalr) and understand that in order to fix your code.

**EDIT 1**

Well, I just realized I mis-read one line in the `Server` class before, which makes things better because that makes it a proper server-side class, but still it is wrong to have your `Server` class instantiated on the client, so overall I think my recommendation is still valid.

**EDIT 2**

Disclaimer: I *never* wrote a single line of production VB.NET code, so treat this as *pseudo* code.

One possible approach could be to make your server also a client. Add the .NET **client** Nuget package, and in your code add this just after starting the server:

```
Dim connection = New Connection(_uri)

AddHandler connection.Received, AddressOf ClientConnected

connection.Start().Wait()
```

You will also remove any explicit usage of `Endpoint` inside `Server`. With this, `Server` should act as a client too, and it should be notified about connections as any other client, therefore your event should trigger as planned.

It's just a starting point, but it should put you on a working track. I never really tried such combo, but it should work.

There would be other ways too (i.e. working around dependency injection), but this should be simple.

I see also potential resource management problems with the `Server` instance in your code, you might have to check that out.

**EDIT 3**

Expanding the dependency injection idea, if you read [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) you can see how you can control the creation of SignalR *artifacts*, including hubs and persistent connections. In your case, you control the lifetime of your `Server` and you could register it inside SignalR's `DependencyResolver` at startup, and then adapt `Endpoint` to receive a `Server` instance in its constructor. This way you can easily see how you can call directly into `Server` from any `Endpoint` created by SignalR when it's doing the broadcasting, hence resolving your problem.

This solution is IMO better than the previous one, which is completely legit but feels more like a hack and overkill, because forces you to use HTTP communications across parts living in the same process.

Comment: the *server class* is never instantiated from the client, in the context of SignalR client/server. The server, startup, & Endpoint classes all live in one file (dll) referenced from a WinForm application that creates ONLY an instance of the *server class*  I agree that it isn't proper to instantiate the endpoint class from the server class but it was an attempt to make things work. I should also note that the code works for client/server communication however, I cant update the winform UI from the *endpoint class* events.

Comment: So, `Form1` lives in the server? I did not expect a Winform app being a SignalR server, but it's "legit". As you also said, creating `Endpoint` where you do it is wrong, SignalR only should control  lifetime of such objects. It is correct that you don't get the event raised, because the `Endpoint` instances serving the clients are created by SignalR, and there's no code in place to subscribe to your event. Suggestion? Have your `Server` class connect to SignalR too, as clients do, and let it listen for `Broadcast` in a handler from which you raise the event. If interested I can expand answer.

Comment: please do expand on your suggestion!